# How to fix header not scrolling with body in datatables table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When scrollx is enabled the header doesn't scroll with the table body.

https://jsfiddle.net/gm90arph

I tried using
        `fixedHeader:true`
with no success.

I expected the header to scroll horizontally with the table body.

Edit:
I want to use the Scroller extension so I don't have any pagination.

Comment: seems like its working in your jsfiddle example. Could you please try to explain further that you are actually asking?

Comment: The header is not scrolling with the body, we can't see the column header name

Comment: Scroll horizontally sorry. Edited my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution after taking a break and looking at my code.

It was because of a small typo. I typed `scrollx: true` instead of `scrollX: true`

Now everything works as expected

https://jsfiddle.net/dg3kcyuf/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: 300,
        scrollX: true,
        scroller: true
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproduce your case, it work normally.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            scrollY: 300,
            scrollX: true,
            scroller: true
        });
    } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Header1</th>
                    <th>Header2</th>
                    <th>Header3</th>
                    <th>Header4</th>
                    <th>Header5</th>
                    <th>Header6</th>
                    <th>Header7</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Header1</th>
                    <th>Header2</th>
                    <th>Header3</th>
                    <th>Header4</th>
                    <th>Header5</th>
                    <th>Header6</th>
                    <th>Header7</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code, there is no scroller plugin, I want to use it so I don't have any pagination.

Comment: Thanks to your code, I found my error. A typo scrollx instead scrollX

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added more unused JS files which is being conflicted with other js

Have a look with this sample

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').DataTable( {
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        paging: false,
        scrollY: 300,
        scrollX: true,
        scroller: true,
        bInfo : false,
        searching : false
    } );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to use Scroller with the table so I don't have any pagination.

Comment: You can remove paging in datatable

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your jsFiddle to make it work the way you want it. The header will now scroll with data as needed. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/toczbega/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({pageLength:25, scrollX: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
      <th>Header5</th>
      <th>Header6</th>
      <th>Header7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Donna Snider</td>
    <td>Customer Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
      <th>Header5</th>
      <th>Header6</th>
      <th>Header7</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```